# UML Equivalents for Functional and Iterative Paradigms

Tags: functional-programming, uml

We know UML is for the OOP paradigm.
Are there any equivalents to UML for the Functional and Iterative paradigms?
I have tried to use UML, but it is based on objects not process.

Comment: You are correct! I searched for "UML for the Functional and Iterative paradigms" but got no hits. Thanks for putting me on track Angel. That thread has been classified off topic, maybe why it didn't turn up in search

Comment: rxjava uses a state timeline diagram to model individual method functionality. http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html. It makes sense for them to model it individually across time because you can chain the methods in any number of ways.